# Верстка таблицами или слоями?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Вопрос на засыпку. Скажите, какой способ разметки страниц на *HTML* лучше?

Таблицами?

```
<table border="1" width="150">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">Шапка</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="50">Меню<br>Меню<br>Меню<br></td>
    <td>Информация...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Или же способ верстки слоями?

```
<div class=1>Шапка</div>
<div class=2>Меню</div>
<div class=2>Меню</div>
<div class=2>Меню</div>
<div class=3>Информация</div>
```

С применением соответствующих таблиц стилей.

Назовите плюсы и минусы первого и второго способа

Comment: Ссылки по "семантике" http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/category/primer/

Comment: Ребята, не надо ссылок. Блоги существуют не для того, чтобы в книжках ковыряться, а быстро и свободно обмениваться знаниями и ОПЫТОМ!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это жесткий вопрос вида: "Что лучше: Windows или Linux?".

У таблиц HTML целевое назначение - это разметка собственно таблиц (курсы валют, расписание самолетов и поездов, турнирная статистика и т.п.), а у элементов div - разметка блоков (div - от слова division, разделение). Но если по каким-то причинам удобнее использовать одно вместо другого это вполне допустимо.

Вообще нужно стремиться к соответствию между тэгами и содержимым тэгов: заголовки - в h, параграфы - в p, списки - в ul, таблицы - table и т.п.

Comment: Угу. И ещё в чём ня блоков - в идеале только стилями можно переразметить страницу полностью, ни капли не трогая содержимое =) А вот таблицу - нет.

Answer (score 3):

Все, что здесь описали, без сомнения, имеет место быть, но:

1. Блочная верстка (или верстка div'ами) часто используется большими проектами не потому что это модно, а потому что рендер страницы идет на порядок быстрее.
2. Табличная верстка используется для предоставления статистических данных, а не как элемент контейнера.

Естественно, блочную и табличную верстку можно совмещать, такой тип называется смешанным.
В чем же выигрывает верстка дивами? Представьте, что у вас, скажем, новостной портал, где выведено 100 последних новостей в колонку:

Верстка таблицей в данном случае сильно тормозит работу браузера, потому что ни один браузер не выведет таблицу ДО ее полной загрузки т.е. от table до /table.
Если же верстка была бы на дивах, то загрузка документа и его рендеринг осуществлялись бы "параллельно" - элемент за элементом.

Что именно использовать Вам - решать только Вам. Но эти плюсы и минусы - это главное отличие.

Answer (score 0):

Яйцо или курица. )) Sun или Microsoft? =)) Прошу прощения. )

Артём, используйте то, что Вам более удобно и не заморачивайтесь на таких мелочах. Что касаемо меня, сам каркас стараюсь делать в дивах, уж не знаю почему... удобней так. Таблицы использую реже, в тех случаях, когда надо, чтоб всё было ровненько и лень прописывать стили для div-ов. Вот собсна и всё. )